# MySQL Query with multiple LIMITS

Tags: mysql, select, limit

Let's say I have the following table with hundreds of toys of various colors...

```
---------------------------
  ITEM  |  COST  |  COLOR
---------------------------
    1   |  12.00 |  BLUE
    2   |  10.98 |  RED
    3   |   9.34 |  BLUE
    4   |  11.33 |  WHITE
    5   |   8.00 |  YELLOW
    .   |    .   |    .
    .   |    .   |    .
    .   |    .   |    .
```

If I wanted to select the three lowest priced blue toys, I could of course write...

```
SELECT * FROM TOYS WHERE Color = 'BLUE' ORDER BY COST LIMIT 3;
```

But, is there a way that I can select the a uniquely specified number of lowest priced yellow, white, and blue toys, as if I were saying...

```
 SELECT * FROM TOYS WHERE COLOR = 'YELLOW' (LIMIT 1) AND COLOR = 'WHITE' (LIMIT 3) AND COLOR = 'BLUE' (LIMIT 2) ORDER BY COST
```

Is it possible to do this fully in MySQL without walking through the array in PHP?

Comment: I am assuming the following would *not* work because it would chew up resources: Execute the complex query without the final WHERE clause (e.g., "COLOR" above); store the results in a temporary table; and then run a much simpler query against the temporary table? Since the website could potentially have hundreds, even thousands, of simultaneous users, there's a chance this query would be executed hundreds of times per second. Am I right in assuming that there's much more overhead in creating and dropping temp tables than having multiple complex queries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not?

```
select * from toys where color = 'Yellow' (LIMIT 1)
UNION
select * from toys where color = 'White' (LIMIT 3)
UNION
select * from toys where color = 'Blue' (LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: I used the simple toy example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. The real query, to which I need to apply the technique, has a few nested queries, joins, etc. It's quite complex.

Comment: Accepted this response because Sparky answered the question that I originally asked. I had not noted the complexity of the query in my original example.

Answer (score 1):

This is working properly

```
(select * from toys where color = 'Yellow' LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(select * from toys where color = 'White' LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO, you were given 2 options here, however, I'll still go by merging the arrays as it won't take so many time/system resources like UNION.
(Based on that you've said the table has a LOT of rows)

Comment: My max row count is probably 50K. The main thing I'm trying to address is that the real query, unlike my example, is very complex, so I wanted to find a way to avoid executing it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

[ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800) could be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLOR ORDER BY COST) AS RN
      FROM TOYS
      WHERE COLOR IN ('YELLOW', 'WHITE', 'BLUE')) sub
WHERE RN <= CASE COLOR WHEN 'YELLOW' THEN 1 WHEN 'WHITE' THEN 3 WHEN 'BLUE' THEN 2 END
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution is create 3 different queries and merge the 3 arrays in PHP

Comment: The OP asks: _"Is it possible to do this fully in MySQL without walking through the array in PHP?"_

Comment: I didn't suggest to walking through, I suggested to merge

Comment: Merging is essentially the same as walking through (a bit more specific, though). The OP clearly did not want to use PHP for this task.

Comment: @Elusive: Yes, thank you. As noted in my comment to Sparky, the real life query is more complex than my simple toy example, so I wanted to see whether there was a more efficient way in MySQL, itself.